# How to split url parameter value

Tags: php, url, parameters, split

how can I split the url param `file.php?subid2=1234567|user@email.com`
in two values `1234567` and email address by using `|` as the splitter?

I'm using `$_REQUEST['subid2'];` to get the complete value but I want to split it in 2 values and save it into cookies.

Thanks

Comment: tried list($id,$email)=explode('|', $_GET['subid2'])?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$values = explode('|', $_GET['subid2']);

// access them like this:
$id = $values[0];
$email = $values[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`list($id, $email) = explode('|', $_GET['subid2']);`

Comment: haha, yeah, I saw your comment and wondered why that wasn't an answer, upvoted it anyway